# Best way to multiply a vector to columns of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix `mymat` and a vector `v`. How can I multiply the vector `v` to each column of matrix `mymat` and get the following result?

```
    mymat = matrix(c(6, 4, 6, 2, 5, 8), nrow=3, ncol=2)
    mymat
    v  =c(2, 4, 6)
    > result
        [,1] [,2]
   [1,]   12    4
   [2,]   16   20
   [3,]   36   48
```

Comment: Did you try `mymat * v`? Isn't that the most obvious way? Plus, as @Xachriel says, your result is wrong.

Comment: @asb they were equivalent results, but still not the same as requested.

Comment: @Xachriel: Because I have the same doubt as you that the output requested is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
    > mymat * v
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   12    4
[2,]   16   20
[3,]   36   48
```

simple as that